# VS Solution unable to open on another machine.

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have created a Web site project using the Visual Studio 2010 Express.
It working fine.
but When I copy the project (With Code files) on another machine.
It shows an error.

```
The Web site 'D:\Project1\MyOnlineWebsite\Website1' does not exist.
```

Only solution is visible to solution explorer other file couldn't load.

Basically, it searches the above path on another machine which does not exist.
What changes should I do in the project before copying on another machine ?

Comment: Is it a copy-paste error?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the solution in a text editor and change the locations of your included project.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the project folder and esp the solution file from the documents folder(Usually saved there in Windows) and try it and see if it works. Is the other machine have same version of visual studio ?